# JavaScript and Google PageSpeed + wp_enqueue_script

Tags: javascript, wp-enqueue-script, seo

The best theme in WordPress theme development requires a standard protocol of enqueuing scripts through `wp_enqueue_script`, but this doesn't solve the problem and Google PageSpeed suffers. I found a solution given by a blogger [here](https://varvy.com/pagespeed/defer-loading-javascript.html):

> Script to call external javascript file
>
> This code should be placed in your HTML just before the `</body>` tag
>   (near the bottom of your HTML file). I highlighted the name of the
>   external JS file.
>
> ```
> <script type="text/javascript">
>     function downloadJSAtOnload() {
>         var element = document.createElement("script");
>         element.src = "defer.js";
>         document.body.appendChild(element);
>     }
>     if (window.addEventListener)
>         window.addEventListener("load", downloadJSAtOnload, false);
>     else if (window.attachEvent)
>         window.attachEvent("onload", downloadJSAtOnload);
>     else window.onload = downloadJSAtOnload;
> </script>
> ```

But that will not use `wp_enqueue_script`. Is there any solution to do this by using `wp_enqueue_script`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can copy this code to a JS file then enqueue that to wordpress .

For Ex :

Copy codes to scripts.js in js folder , then in `functions.php` write :

```
function enqueue_scripts() { 
    wp_register_script('scripts', get_template_directory_uri(). '/js/scripts.js','', '', true);
    wp_enqueue_script('scripts');
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts','enqueue_scripts' );
```